# Checking html5 and Javascript support

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello i would like to check if ALL features of HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript are supported in my browser before redirecting the user to the application itself, i have seen some references to Modernizr but even after reading their documentation i can't make heads or tails of how to use it.

I just want a simple function that returns a boolean after the check has been made.  Is there any sort of function like that out there somewhere?

Comment: I'm dying to see what page you're building that needs EVERY html, css3 and js (??) feature.

Comment: Lol okay that was funny, i honestly cannot remember where i used html5 features in my application and the code is soo much that going through is a pain, so i was just wondering if i could just check for all.

Comment: Since no browser supports *all* those features, you can skip the test entirely and just redirect everybody away from your application.

Comment: @Quentin I am asking for help here, if you know better then give me a logical solution else please refrain from making such comments.

Comment: @BlankEDjok — You've rejected trying to detect the features you are actually using. Detecting all features isn't going to work (as mentioned above). What sort of comment would you like?

Comment: @Quentin Please read my comment again, i was ASKING if it was possible to check for all, i did not reject anybody's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Life (and browser compatibility) is more complicated than a single boolean.

Use Modernizr, then make sure all the *specific* features you actually need are supported and do your redirect, for example:
`if(Modernizr.geolocation && Modernizr.boxshadow/* whatever else ...*/) {...}`

You tagged your question as 'php' - but reliable feature detection can only run on the client side. If you want this info on the server you can run the tests client side and then pass the interesting results in a cookie or something similar.

Comment: Also to detect Javascript then you're best to use Javascript to do the redirect

Comment: @Dean Whitehouse What? Sorry i don't get you.

Comment: @BlankEDjok Have suggested an edit but to detect Javascript you just need to put the redirect in the Javascript, if Javascript is disabled it'll never run